# Is crontab running old version of file?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, crontab

This has been driving me crazy: I run a set of Python scripts once per hour on a Raspberry Pi. I updated one of the scripts, but even after a reboot, it still seems to run an old version of the file.

The command in `/etc/crontab`:

```
0 * * * * python ~/Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py
```

I've transferred the file several times, and checked the file on the Pi to make sure the new version overwrote the old one. Everything looks ok. I can also run the script directly from the command line and it works as expected.

Is there any way it's running an old version of the file? I cannot figure out what's happening here!

Comment: If you can run the correct script from the command prompt, exactly what are you typing there?  Also please type `pwd` at the command prompt and tell us what it returns.

Comment: To run the script, I type `python /Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py` – basically just the full path to the script. `pwd` returns `/home/pi`.

Comment: There is a difference there... The ~ is replaced with the home directory making the effective path /home/pi/Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py which is not the same as /Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py

Comment: Hmm, true but running either command via the command line has the same result for me.

Comment: So that mean copies of the script do exist at both /Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py and /home/pi/Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py  Plz check what version of the script exists in both locations.  Cron will be running the /home/pi/Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py version.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something: there's no folder `Desktop` in the root directory, just `bin`, `etc`, `lib`, etc. The `home/pi/Desktop` folder is definitely the one I've been updating.

Comment: I'm going off what you said above.  You said typed `python /Desktop/MyCoolPythonScript.py` at the command prompt.

Comment: I should go ahead and add that when I started asking questions I thought the outcome might be the difference between user pi and user root.  What you typed at the command prompt led me to believe you had created a /Desktop/ directory at the root, and as a result had two different copies of the script in different places.

Comment: Thanks, I could totally see that happening. In this case, I'm pretty sure it's a weird cron-related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some times it won't re compile the python code if there is a compiled version. In the same directory there will be a .pyc file.  Delete that file. Then see if it will run the new python Script

Comment: Smart! I don't see the .pyc file though... If I run the script directly from the command line it works (updated question with this).